# AngularJS: how to prevent programmatic clicking of button that hits AJAX endpoint from client?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I discovered a security vulnerability with my app and I would like to fix it.

On my homepage there is a button and when clicked it triggers a record to be created in my database. I would like to prevent someone from programmatically clicking this button a zillion times in effect creating a zillion records in my db.

I tried creating a function which sets `disabled="true"` after my button is clicked but it seems like the programatic looping and clicking beats it to the punch.

Any suggestions of how to patch this hole?

Comment: Have you considered instead of throwing it straight to your target table you effectively buffer it into another table that contains a datetime stamp and IP of the user clicking it? Then just move unique values to your true target.

Comment: You cannot protect yourself against this happening client-side; there will always be a way around it. Check it on the server first before storing it in the DB.

Comment: check session on server  , if from this session already added then return false and disable button

Answer (score 0):

as already suggested, there is no way guarantee the security on client side. 
But this does not say it is not useful to do some client side check before hitting the backend. A useful technique is to use javascript timer, as suggested 
    `http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2674-creating-a-reusable-timer-in-angularjs.htm`.
On the backend side, you probably need to put some info in your session, preferably not the in the db, to reduce database hit.